# How to use Postgresql Database in Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, entity-framework, ado.net

I'am trying to use Entity Framework with Postgresql Database in my Silverlight application ,for that I am using npgsql data provider .

Fowlowing this link I registered Npgsql and Mono.Security in the GAC, and I added a provider factory entry into section of machine.config. I created a .edmx file with EdemGen2 and finaly I added a string connexion to my app.config as follows:

```
<add name="PostgreDatabase" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EspaceModel.csdl|res://*/EspaceModel.ssdl|res://*/EspaceModel.msl;        provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;        Port=5432;Encoding=WIN1252;Server=localhost;        Database=postgis;UserId=postgres;Password=admin&quot;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
```

But, I still can't access my data. Any Help ?

Comment: SilverLight = Client-side. Is that where you try to do this?  Or in the backend server where it belongs?